# Multi-Line select with Alt

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I select multi-line with vscode?

On Visual Studio you can press left alt key and select multi-lines, but it is not working with vscode.

Comment: **See instead:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384442/does-visual-studio-code-have-box-select-multi-line-edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 2017, it is possible. Read the [release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_add-multiple-cursors-with-ctrl-cmd-click):

> We have introduced a new setting, `editor.multiCursorModifier`, to
>   change the modifier key for applying multiple cursors to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click on
>   macOS and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on Windows and Linux. This lets users coming from
>   other editors such as Sublime Text or Atom continue to use the
>   keyboard modifier they are familiar with.
>
> The setting can be set to:
>
> - ctrlCmd - Maps to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> on macOS.
> - <kbd>alt</kbd> - The existing default Alt.

Answer (score 2):

It is not available for now, but there is a feature request on uservoice:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7761561-vertical-text-selection

Comment: **LINK NO LONGER WORKS** THIS FORUM HAS BEEN DEPRECATED!

Answer (score 0):

The box-selection feature in Visual Studio (where you can highlight a part of multiple lines) isn't available in VSCode.

For features like this that you would love to see in VSCode - you can add the idea to the [Code User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code) pages.

Comment: Thank you. I did my vote there just now. It is a good feature to miss.