# Does Visual Studio Code have box select/multi-line edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I heard Microsoft released a new editor called Visual Studio Code and it looks pretty good. One key feature that I need is multi-line edit and I can't seem to find anything about it having it.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29953479/465053).

Comment: From April 2018 (version 1.23), we can use middle mouse button to select multiple columns. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_column-selection-using-middle-mouse-button

Comment: Related solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580788/585398

Answer (score 356, accepted):

Box Selecting

Windows & Linux: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 'Mouse Left Button'

macOS: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + 'Click'

<kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit selection.

MacOS: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + 'arrow key'

Comment: Is there any way to change this shortcut? I can't find the related entry in the key bindings.

Comment: Here I am having a box selection issue. I can select a box, but pasting does not work for me, I tried Command + V and a few variations, but I just get a usual paste and never a box-paste.

Comment: Probably issue is related to your environment,  i can only recommend to  reinstall vscode as i don't have information about configurations.

Comment: Who the hell, just down voted this answer while I was reading and gonna + 1 this.... ~_~

Comment: to paste, use the same keys used to select, and select just a straight column (0-width), then paste.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I just tested this on July 23 2017 and it seems like just holding `alt` does the trick in windows. It had some weird behavior if holding `shift` + `alt` as described above. This is what you want if your goal is simply to paste contents of the clipboard into multiple lines at once.

Comment: This is correct answer

Comment: shift+option+click doesn't work on my macbook. any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: check your settings `cmd+,` and keyboard bindings `cmd+k s`

Comment: This just creates a selection _from_ the current cursor, _to_ where you click.  What if you wanna just "drag a square" to create one, ala Sublime (middle-click mouse + drag) or VS (alt + drag)?

Comment: the original answer was with cmd and not with shift i don’t know why someone changed this, actually i rejected this change

Comment: @HovhannesSanoyan Shouldn't it be _Shift + Alt + 'Mouse Left Button'_ for Windows? That's the default for me anyway and I just installed Code yesterday

Comment: @AlexMcMillan You can start dragging from where you want the selection to start **before** you hold down _Shift + Alt_ down to create a block selection as you describe it :)

Comment: rollback of correct, original answer

Comment: @Boregore that's better, but still not what I'm after.  Try grabbing the last few chars of several lines, which have shorter lines between them... you *have* to be careful about where you start - it's got a very "terminal" feel to it, as opposed to the "whiteboard" feel of eg Sublime.

Comment: Fantastic. This is super useful though I don't understand why VS Code can't just be like every other major editor (on Windows) and use ALT+left mouse button to do this. Gotta be different, I suppose

Comment: It's a shame, that it is not working the same as in normal Visual Studio, especially because the combination of [Shift]+[Alt] changes language settings.

Comment: when it does work its not as good as any other idea.  you can't box select unless characters already exist such as spaces

Answer (score 34):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> to insert cursors below or above.

Comment: Note: Your graphics card provider might overwrite these default shortcuts.

Comment: You may want to edit your shortcuts. Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

As an example:[
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+numpad2",         "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },{ "key": "ctrl+alt+numpad8",           "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" }
]

Answer (score 21):

The shortcuts I use in Visual Studio for multiline (aka box) select are <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + up/down/left/right

To create this in Visual Studio Code you can add these keybindings to the keybindings.json file (menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard shortcuts*).

```
{ "key": "shift+alt+down", "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+up", "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
                                 "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+right", "command": "cursorRightSelect",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+left", "command": "cursorLeftSelect",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

Comment: This is good, but not great as it doesn't _quite_ act the same as box selection in other applications. e.g. If I do `shift+alt+down` 3 times and then `shift+alt+up` once, rather than undoing my last down arrow key press so that only 2 rows are selected, it adds the row above the 1st one I had selected, so I end up with 4 rows selected. Also, you need to press `Esc` to get out of the box selection mode. I wish VS Code would provide native keyboard-box-selection support, but this answer is the next best thing 

Answer (score 13):

For multiple select in Visual Studio Code, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and starting clicking wherever you want to edit.

Visual Studio Code supports multiple line edit.

Comment: I expected this to work, but it doesn't.  Instead it acts like a regular mouse-click-n-drag.

Comment: @jmoreno I had the same issue - only Shift+Alt+Click worked, until I did this: go to Selection menu, and select Switch to Alt+Click for Multi-Cursor.

Comment: You may also want to go to Selection and choose 'Switch to Ctrl+Click' for multi-cursor selection if you find alt clicking to not work..

Answer (score -1):

On Windows it's holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while box selecting. Once you have your selection then attempt your edit.