# How do I add a new cursor at the next occurrence of selected text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Sublime Text, I can use Ctrl+D or Command+D (Mac OS) to quickly add new cursors at the next occurrence(s) of the currently selected text. How can I do this in VSCode?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Benjamin. For reference, this functionality has been added (since v0.3.0):

- ⌘D selects the word at the cursor, or the next occurrence of the current selection.
- ⌘K ⌘D moves the last added cursor to next occurrence of the current selection.
- ⌘U undoes the last cursor action.

Answer (score 1):

We are preparing for a new version of VS Code that will have this feature enabled. It should be released next week!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Benjamin - I would recommend this is deleted now, as 0.3 is out - and future readers may become confused. Thanks again for the excellent product your team is putting together

Answer (score 0):

Box Selecting

Windows : 'shift' + 'alt' + 'Mouse Left Button'

macOS : 'shift' + 'option' + 'Click'

[answer taken from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384442/does-visual-studio-code-have-box-select-multi-line-edit/36650448#36650448)